# How to choose an image for DataflowPipelineWorkerPoolOptions.setDiskSourceImage

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Are there any special requirements for images that can be used with the aforementioned method?
Simply choosing one of the images in the images section does not seem to work.

Thanks,
G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method currently cannot use images other than the ones set by Dataflow.

Thanks for your patience in these early stages of the service.

r